# Walter White meets Lionel Messi

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

*Walter White and Lionel Messi became close friends. Because of their busy schedules, they are able to meet only four times a year.*

---

*White is free in July but Messi is not.

Messi is free in August but White is not.*

---

*The four times they meet in a year are spent on:*

> 1. *Watching old clips of Rene Higuita.*
> 2. *Watching the documentary 'Tembo'.*
> 3. *Enjoying a meal of Trucha a la parrilla in Argentina.*
> 4. *Attending a bullfighting event in Spain.*

---

- *Watching old clips of Rene Higuita will be in November.*
- *Watching the documentary 'Tembo' will be in December.*

---

1. ***In which month will they enjoy a meal of Trucha a la parrilla in Argentina?***
2. ***In which month will they attend a bullfighting event in Spain?***

Answer (score 14, accepted):

White and Messi will arrange their schedules so that...

> ...they will eat 'Trucha a la parrilla' in **March**, and attend the bullfighting in **May**.

Because this puzzle is all about:

> astrological **[star signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrological_sign)**. Specifically, the symbols behind the star signs and the month in which they *mainly* fall (since star signs cross two months, but not equally - in each case here, we need the *second* month in which they fall).

First note that:

> [Walter White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_White_(Breaking_Bad)) from *Breaking Bad* is diagnosed with stage III lung *cancer*. This connection with **Cancer** (22 June - 22 July) explains why he is 'free' in **July**.
>
>  [Lionel Messi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi) is also known as '**Leo**' - the star sign for 23 July to 22 August, explaining why he is 'free' in August.

As for the four events:

> each of these has a connection to a star sign symbol, and takes place in the second month connected with that star sign.
>
>  [Rene Higuita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Higuita) was a goalkeeper renowned for performing '[the *Scorpion* Kick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRj3dKKp9tI)'. This link with scorpions leads us to **Scorpio** (23 October - 22 November), hence the **November** meeting.
>
>  The documentary [*Tembo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tembo_(film)) involves an *archer* hunting with a bow and arrow. This connects with the archer sign, **Sagittarius** (23 November - 21 December), hence the **December** meeting.

So we can work out the other two:

> 'Trucha a la parrilla' is a *fish* dish, leading us to **Pisces** (19 February - 20 March), hence **March**.
>
>  *Bull*fighting leads us to **Taurus** (20 April - 20 May), hence **May**.